# org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi-bundle, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to setup my eclipse plugin development target and receive the following error multiple times:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt 4 0 2015-01-30 15:15:06.879
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt [955]
Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core; bundle-version="0.9.0"
-> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core; bundle-version="0.10.100.v20140424-2042"; singleton:="true"
   org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core [1134]
     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.batik.css; bundle-version="1.7.0"
       -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.batik.css; bundle-version="1.7.0.v201011041433"
          org.apache.batik.css [1177]
            Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.w3c.dom.events; version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"
```

Does this mean that none of these plugins can be resolved, or just not the last one `org.w3c.dom.events` or is this a result from the mismatch of the bundle versions of `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core`?

Answer (score 5):

for JMC 8 The minimum JDK requirement is version=8, for JMC 8.1 The minimum JDK requirement is version=11

you are facing this issue because you are trying to open JMC 8.1 with JDK 8. Install JMC version 8 then your issue will resolve.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

It is just `org.w3c.dom.events` that can't be resolved.

You should have a `org.w3c.dom.events` plugin.

If you are setting up a target platform for plugin development the easiest thing to use is everything in the 'Eclipse SDK' download form http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/

Comment: org.w3c.dom.events (3.0.0.draft...) is available and checked both in the target plattforms content tab and in the run configuration Plug-Ins tab, when I manually select the plugins. So I don't understand why it can't be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. It turned out, I was missing the org.w3c.dom.events plugin in my dependencies in my product file or launch configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue despite the module being present. I found that it was a caching problem in Windows.

I deleted the contents of: C:/users/UserName/.eclipse

Afterwards, Eclipse started fine.

Answer (score -1):

Had a similar problem for a different plugin.

Here is my error:

**eclipse org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: oracle.eclipse.tools.jaxrs.v11**

I use java 8 and 17 together in my system. So when I add the below field to my eclipse.ini file, it solved the problem for me:

```
-vm

C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_341/bin/javaw.exe (That should be your own jdk path)
```

I hope it helps people who are currently dealing with similar issues.